# How to read a paragraph from cli for a message body using Java

Tags: java, cmd

I'm working on a program which reads and writes an Excel file containing data about different companies, such as its location, telephone number and e-mail addresses. Since I'm still studying in college and I haven't studied yet how to make a proper interface, the program runs as a cmd window, and you have to navigate through the program's menu writing text using `keyboard.nextLine()` each time you want to pass to the next line.

One of the functionalities of the program will be sending a personalized mail to a specific or a list of companies using the associated e-mail address. The struggle comes when I ask the user to write the body paragraph of the message. Since I'm using `keyboard.nextLine()` for inputs, each time that the user would want to pass to the next line using the "Intro" key, the Scanner will stop reading. I could make a method to keep adding the String input to a String variable until the user say so, but I would want the user to be completely able and free to write, re-write and delete the message as much as he/she wants; so using this idea would be too annoying for the user.

I've thought about opening a text file as a window right when the user have to write down the text and then making the program write that file into a String variable; but I haven't been able to implement this succesfully. I've tried to recycle a method I found to clear the cmd window, changing the `clear` command to `text.txt`, but it didn't work at all:

```
public static void openText(){

    try {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } else {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:Body.txt");
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

So, I would like to know how to either open an editable text window as I've thought to do or another solution to this problem that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at Swing?

It's not that much harder than doing command line interactions.

Basically what you need is a JFrame with a JTextArea in it and an 'OK' button.

Here's a nice example with even cut/copy/paste buttons in it:
[Java Swing | Create a simple text editor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-create-a-simple-text-editor/)

Comment: Yeah, this might work. Thanks! I can even understand more or less the example so I can implement this safely in my program.

I'd like to know how to do the idea I had in mind, though... Just for curiosity, this solution is way better that the one I had in mind; but you know, just in case I might need it in the future.

Comment: Multi-line editing in the cli is very hard to do using only the java Console API. So you would need to launch a real text editor, and provide a temporary text file for it. On Windows, that would probably be notepad, on linux systems you have nano or vi.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad c:\temp\Body.txt")